# Database table design with a public and private id in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, database-schema

I have several related tables which have public and private id columns. Public id is exposed to the Internet, private id is not.

```
CREATE TABLE cart (
  private_id SERIAL,
  public_id UUID default gen_random_uuid()
);

CREATE TABLE product(
  private_id SERIAL,
  public_id UUID default gen_random_uuid()
);

CREATE TABLE cart_item(
  private_id SERIAL,
  public_id UUID default gen_random_uuid(),
  cart_id INT references cart(private_id)
  product_id INT references product(private_id)
);
```

The problem I have with the above design is that when I query for the cart items alone, I have to join the items with the cart and product to get their public ids.

```
SELECT p.public_id, c.public_id, ci.public_id 
FROM cart c JOIN cart_item ci ON c.private_id = ci.cart_id
JOIN product p ON ci.product_id = p.private_id
```

What would be the best way of designing the public/private id concept and limiting amount of joins required to get public ids?

One way of simplifying it would be to convert private id to UUID and expose them - Tom Harrison Jr doesn't approve.

Another way would be to denormalise public ids along with the private ones - how do I keep private id and public id in sync?

Edit:
Inserting data into `cart_item` is also problematic. The private id of cart and product have to be resolved with public id (the client has access only to public id):

```
INSERT INTO cart_item(cart_id, product_id) VALUES (
  SELECT private_id FROM cart WHERE public_id = ?,
  SELECT private_id FROM product WHERE public_id = ?
)
```

Comment: There is no reason to limit the number of joins.  You can hide them in a view, if that makes your life easier.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff, the views make no any difference. Updated the question.

Comment: Views could make a difference here too, if you'd put triggers on them doing the actual insert including the resolving.

Comment: @stickybit Could you elaborate, please?